# How to integrate third party library in magento 2 extension?

Tags: magento2

I am developing test (Custom Magento Extension) module and I want to integrate third party library into my Magento 2 extension which will be using files under this library.
Can anyone suggest how to integrate it into extension ? 
API I am trying to integrate does not follow zend naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

You should do two steps to work with that library:

1. Download it with your module
2. Make it available to the autoloader

The best way to solve all these steps is to find your library in [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) and add it as a dependency in your module's composer.json.

If it is not available as composer package, you have another two options:

1. Declare its package as a [repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories) and add dependency in 'required' section
2. Bundle it inside your package

Also if it's not a composer package, you'll need to configure your autoloader to work with that library. [Here is a documentation for that.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

Comment: can you please let me know for https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf lib Because I didn't get it , I want to use this lib without composer in my extension.

Comment: How can we use library without composer in Magento2.2 ?
As putting custom library in lib folder works fine in Magento2.1.9 but it is not working in Magento2.2

Comment: can u explain how to bundle it inside package