# Magento 2 external library folder

Tags: magento2, module, external, 3rd-party-library, filesystem

I am trying to keep the google library files but confused on the destination folder. In magento 1.9 we can  kept in lib folder.
Can any one please give the solution for that

Answer (score 2):

From the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_conventions.html

> If you want to use a library the recommended location for the
>   component is `<your Magento install dir>/lib/<Vendor_Library>`

If you're having trouble regarding the autoloader I suggest you look up those Magento StackExchange Q&A:

- [how to include 3rd party library in magento 2 (like php xlsx library)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100766/how-to-include-3rd-party-library-in-magento-2-like-php-xlsx-library)
- [Including generated 3rd party PHP library in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96690/including-generated-3rd-party-php-library-in-magento2)
- [How to integrate third party library in magento 2 extension?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133387/how-to-integrate-third-party-library-in-magento-2-extension/133490)

Comment: Thank you Raphael , How can i call those library in my helper

Comment: @Ramesh I've added some links to other questions on SE that could help u

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism if I will put library into <your Magento install dir>/lib/<Vendor_Library>. how to use and into my extension.